# dockerfile is not updating new content

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

My docker file doesn't update code.
My changes of app.py aren't available. 
Container has still 1st version of app.py

I tried docker system prune -f

```
      -app
          -Dockerfile
          -app.py
          -requirements.txt
          -wsgi.py
      -docker-compose.yaml
```

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine3.9

LABEL MAINTAINER="Jay Prakash jaymailbox2012@gmail.com"

ENV GROUP_ID=1000 \
    USER_ID=1000

COPY . /var/www/
WORKDIR /var/www/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install gunicorn
RUN addgroup -g $GROUP_ID www
RUN adduser -D -u $USER_ID -G www www -s /bin/sh

USER www

EXPOSE 5001

CMD [ "gunicorn", "-w", "4", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5001", "wsgi"]
```

Comment: what should be change and does not ?

Comment: @LinPy my code changes in app.py doesn't reflect in container app.py.

Comment: yes please provide what should be change and does not

Comment: @LinPy
 app.py is flask app. I am trying to add more route in that but new changes aren't available in container.

Comment: stop all your containers then try to delete all  images `docker rmi $(docker images -q)`

Comment: gunicorn won't reload on code changes. You should use `flask run` instead. And make sure that there is a volume to map between your code from host machine and inside your container.

Comment: What steps do you take when you change your code?  (Generally I'd run `pytest` locally outside of Docker, and once I'm convinced it works, `docker build` a new image, `docker stop && docker rm` the old container, and `docker run` a new container.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

command should be `docker system prune -a`

And `docker-compose up` never updates the image if there is already there.